# React-native Redux - Have two state changement with onPress

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm working on a React-native application, using Redux.
I'm new to javascript/react langage.

I use Auth0 for authenticate user on app, and i would like to manage my "Log in"/"Log out" button. Actually, when i click on the "Log in" button, the string change on "Log out", but i don't know how it can comeback to the initial state, in this case, comeback to "Log in" string.

My authReducer.js

```
import {
  BUTTON_LOGOUT,
  BUTTON_LOGIN
} from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  logButton: 'Log in'
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BUTTON_LOGOUT:
      return { logButton: 'Log out' };
    case BUTTON_LOGIN:
      return { INITIAL_STATE };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

My authActions.js

```
import { BUTTON_LOGOUT, BUTTON_LOGIN } from './types';

export const logInToLogOut = () => {
    return ({ type: BUTTON_LOGOUT });
}

export const logOutToLogIn = () => {
    return ({ type: BUTTON_LOGIN });
}
```

My render method in LoginForm.js

```
render = () => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <CardSection>
          <Text style={styles.textStyle}>
            Login page
          </Text>
        </CardSection>
        <CardSection style={styles.buttonSectionStyle}>
          <Button onPress={this.props.logInToLogOut} title={this.props.logButton} />
        </CardSection>
      </Card>
    );
  }
```

I know that i'm using only one action inside "onPress=" but i've tried many  things for doing this, that's why i kept the code that handles the change between "log in" to "log out" without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my problem !
I think I had to write badly this toggle method yesterday..

```
 toggleButtonLabel = () => {
    if (this.props.logButton === 'Log in') {
      this.props.logInToLogOut();
    } else {
      this.props.logOutToLogIn();
    }
  }
```

Comment: This solution is functionally the same as the second suggestion I had in my answer. Just so you know.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do a toggle login action, that toggles between two states, like so

```js
// In the reducer 
case BUTTON_LOGIN_TEXT_TOGGLE: {
      const previousText = state.logButton;
      const newText = previousText == 'Log in' ? 'Log out' : 'Login';
      return { logButton: newText }
}
```

And then dispatch that through the onClick function.

**Or** you could, depending on the value of your components `this.props.logButton`, make the onClick (onPress?) function be different functions.

```js
// inside render
const {logButton, logInToLogOut, logOutToLogIn} = this.props;
const onClick = 
   logButton ==  'Login' ? logInToLogOut : logOutToLogIn;

return (
   // other stuff here
   <Button onPress={onClick} title={logButton} />
)
```

Both these solutions use **[the ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/sv-SE/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)**, which is very useful for things like this (but could be replaced with if/else statements);